# Let $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n, A = u\cdot v^T$ then prove $\|A\|_2 = \|u\|_2 \; \|v\|_2$

Tags: normed-spaces

> Let $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n, A = u\cdot v^T$ then  prove $\|A\|_2 = \|u\|_2 \; \|v\|_2$

How can I do this? I'm kinda stuck with this 2-norm of the matrix.

If it would be $\|A\|_{\text{frob}}$ then I think I could prove this:

#### Proof:

Let $u = \begin{pmatrix}u_1\\ \ldots\\ u_n\end{pmatrix}$ and $v = \begin{pmatrix}v_1\\ \ldots\\ v_n\end{pmatrix}$

Then $u\cdot v^T = \begin{pmatrix} u_1v_1 & u_1v_2 & \ldots& u_1v_n\\
u_2v_1 &u_2v_2 & \ldots & u_2v_n\\
\vdots &   & \ddots & \vdots\\
u_nv_1 & u_nv_2 & \ldots & u_nv_n\end{pmatrix}$

Then $a_{ij} = u_i\cdot v_j$ and

$$\begin{align*}
 \|A\|_{\text{frob}}^2 &= \sum_{i,j} (u_i\cdot v_j)^2\\
 &= \sum_i u_i^2 \sum_j v_j^2\\
 &= \|u\|_2^2 \cdot \|v\|_2^2
\end{align*}$$

#### However?

This can't be right can it? There is a difference between the 2-matrix norm and the Frobenius-norm...

I don't see how I prove it using the 2-norm as it uses eigenvalues..

Could someone provide some pointers?

Comment: How have you defined $\|A\|_2$?

Comment: Actually it was defined as $$\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{\rho(A^TA)}$$ where $\rho(A) = \max_i|\lambda_i|$ with $\lambda_i$ the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\left\| Ax \right\|_{2}^{2} :=\left<Ax, Ax\right> = \left|\left<v,x\right>\right|^{2}\left\|u\right\|_{2}^{2} \le \left\|u\right\|_{2}^{2}\left\|v\right\|_{2}^{2} \left\|x\right\|_{2}^{2}
\end{align}
So $\left\|A \right\|_{2} \le \left\|u\right\|_{2}\left\|v\right\|_{2}$. On the other hand, taking $x = v/\left\|v\right\|$ gives
\begin{align}
\left\|Ax \right\|_{2} = \left\|uv^{T}v\right\|_{2}/\left\|v\right\|_{2} = \left\|u\right\|_{2}\left\|v\right\|_{2}
\end{align}
$\left\|A\right\|_{2} = \left\|u\right\|_{2}\left\|v\right\|_{2}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate the second equality further?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant: $$\left<Ax, Ax\right> \stackrel{?}{=} \left|\left<v,x\right>\right|^{2}\left\|u\right\|_{2}^{2}$$ Thanks for supplementary information though :)

Comment: $u\cdot v^{T}x = \left<v,x\right>u$.

Comment: Hmm, this statement is equivalent, is it not? $$\|Ax\|_2^2 = \|u\cdot v^Tx\|_2^2 = |v^T x|^2\cdot \|u\|_2^2$$ Since $v^T x \in \mathbb{R}$ and this could be written as $\left< v,x\right>$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct it was bad form to switch between notations mid-stream.